# TypeError with all my print functions: "TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable"

Tags: python, printing, typeerror, google-colaboratory

I just started out with Python and wanted to use a print function on my code in Colab. However, all my print functions are now giving the same error: "TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable".

Therefore I tried a simple

`print("Hello")`

and even that function is giving the same error. What happened? Everything was working well yesterday.

Below also the code that I used to upload my table.

`

```
#upload weather data
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

weer = pd.read_csv("weather_netherlands.csv")

df = pd.DataFrame(weer)
```

`

When I opened a new notebook, the same print function did work.

Comment: Sounds like you assigned a tuple to the name "print" somewhere in your code - something like `print = (1, 2)`

Comment: You probably have `print = (,)` somewhere in your code. Don't assign values to builtins and reserved keywords.

Comment: try to use pycharm and start a new project

Comment: I searched the entire document for "print =" but couldn't find it anywhere. I copied everything to a new notebook and it does work now, but I have still no idea why. I didn't change anything.

Comment: It seems it was indeed something related to colab. Colab also saved and used by previous variables even though I had deleted them. After selecting 'Runtime' > 'Restart and run all' from the menu, the program worked again as normal.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are using colab, the uploading file method you are using will not work.
Import the following files:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/gdrive")

df = pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/My Drive/weather_netherlands.csv')

df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same issue and I also imported my file using the same method as you do.
I also restarted my notebook and it worked pretty well.

Comment: It would be beneficial to include *why* restarting works, which seems (according to comments and answers), to be related to Colab caching variables from old sessions.